# Common Lisp reading from file and storing as list

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

So doing some common lisp exercises and everything was going well until I encountered this strange behaviour. I read text from file (brown.txt) into a variable *corpus*, and it's supposed to be stored as a list. However, i suspect that it's not, even though it sometimes works like one, but fails at other times.

Here is the basic read from file -> append for a list -> store list in *corpus* stuff (split / tokenized on whitespace):

```
(defun tokenize (string)
  (loop
     for start = 0 then (+ space 1)
     for space = (position #\space string :start start)
     for token = (subseq string start space)
     unless (string= token "") collect token
     until (not space)))

(defparameter *corpus*
   (with-open-file (stream "./brown.txt" :direction :input)
     (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
           while line
           append (tokenize line))))
```

And below are 2 expressions that should both work, yet only the latter does (the *corpus* one). The first one returns NIL.

```
(loop for token in *corpus* do
     (print token))
*corpus*
```

I suspect that it has to do with reading from file as a *stream* object, and that the (append ...) does not create a list from this stream, but instead lazy waits until i want to evaluate it later or sumth, and at that later time it just decides not to work anymore?? (makes little sense to me).

Comment: None of the standard Common Lisp functions are lazy.

Comment: `APPEND` can't tell and doesn't care where the list came from. A list is a list is a list.

Comment: `LOOP` returns `NIL` unless it has a `RETURN <expression>` statement or uses one of the collection verbs. Why do you expect the first expression to return something? It will print the list elements as a side effect, but not return them.

Comment: @Barmar
Hmm, but i would have thought that the _collect_ on the _unless_ keyword of the loop would mean that it returns a list upon completion (when _until_ is satisfied)

Comment: Yes, `TOKENIZE` returns a list. But your `(loop for token...)` expression doesn't have `COLLECT` in it, so it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This expression:

```
(loop for token in *corpus* do
     (print token))
```

returns `NIL` because it has no `RETURN` clause or an accumulation clause (e.g. `COLLECT` or `APPEND`). It simply calls `PRINT` repeatedly, but discards its return value.